# How to lookup a multi-value Name in a hashtable?

Tags: powershell

If I have a hashtable with a multi-value Name, how do I specify the Name when I do a lookup?

Here are some contrived examples ...

```
$unary = @{
    $false, "!A";
    $true,  "A"
}

$unary
Name                           Value
----                           -----
False                          !A
True                           A

$unary[$false]
!A
$unary[$true]
A
```

So far so good.

```
$binary = @{
  ($false, $false) = "!A and !B"
  ($false, $true)  = "!A and B"
  ($true,  $false) = "A and !B"
  ($true,  $true)  = "A and B"
}

$binary
Name                           Value
----                           -----
{False, True}                  !A and B
{True, False}                  A and !B
{True, True}                   A and B
{False, False}                 !A and !B

$binary[$false, $true]
//Nothing
$binary[($false, $true)]
//Nothing
$binary[{$false, $true}]
//Nothing
//www.stackoverflow.com... :)
```

What do I need to specify in `$binary[...]` to get a value?

Comment: No way! Forget it! It would work in other languages (for example in **Ruby** works), not in posh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using arrays as keys in a hash table. Just to illustrate what goes wrong here:

```
PS Home:\> $x=$false,$false
PS Home:\> $y=@($binary.Keys)[0]
PS Home:\> $x
False
False
PS Home:\> $y
False
False
PS Home:\> $x.Equals($y)
False
```

Both objects also have different hashcodes. They won't ever be a good idea to use as keys in hash tables, as you cannot extract the values again, unless using the exact same references you put into the hash table.

The easier eay would probably be to use a single object as key:

```
$binary = @{
  0 = "!A and !B"
  1  = "!A and B"
  10 = "A and !B"
  11  = "A and B"
}
```

or similar. Then extracting

```
$binary[01]
```

will yield `"!A and B"` as expected.

Note also that a List will have the same problem with equality. Tuples might work, but those aren't available in .NET 2.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why it doesn't work. I went with a combination of your answer (make a single value key) and mjolinor's (make the combined key a string).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a not so honnest solution, but depending on what you want to do it can help.

```
$unary = new-object ‘object[]’ 2
$unary[$false] = "!A"
$unary[$true] = "A"

$binary= new-object ‘object[,]’ 2,2
$binary[$false,$false] = "!A and !B"
$binary[$false,$true] = "!A and B"
$binary[$true,$false] = "A and !B"
$binary[$true,$true] = "A and B"
```

Result :

```
PS > $binary[$true,$true]
A and B
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you wanted to see, but:

```
$binary = @{
  [string]($false,$true)  = "!A and B"
  [string]($true,$false) = "A and !B"
  [string]($true,$true)  = "A and B"
}

$binary[[string]($false,$true)]


!A and B
```

Comment: `"$($false,$true)"` would be a shorter way of doing this. Or just `"False True"` :-)

Comment: That is shorter.  Either way, it's basically the same answer as the one you posted, which is to get the keys down to a scalar.

Comment: Indeed. It's subtle, though. And requires a bit knowledge of .NET. If you came to PowerShell from C# it's probably fairly obvious, but otherwise ...

Comment: Thanks, converting my multi-value keys to a string was an easy change to what I already had, and it just worked.